# JavaScript function argument in apostrophe

Tags: javascript, function, variables, onclick, arguments

Okay, I have a quick question. I have spent all night and day searching and trying methods of displaying function arguments inside of ' (apostrophes). Here is the code I'm trying to call.

```
function openEventAdd(month,day,year)
    {
        $.modal({
            title: 'Add Event',
            url: "event_add.php?m=" + month + "&d=" + day + "&y=" + year,
            width: 300
        });
    };
```

I'm trying to use the onclick in a url tag to call this function using certain parameters called by the link. I cannot figure out how to get the argument to be displayed in the "URL" part.

I have researched this a bunch, and cannot come up with a conclusion. 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is my anchor that calls the function.

```
<a onclick=\"openEventAdd($current_month,$current_day,$current_year)\">'.$i.'</a>
```

Comment: `<a href="#" onclick="openEventAdd(3,22,2012)">Click</a>` doesn't work?

Comment: Can you show how you try to call it?

Comment: "How to get the argument to be displayed in the URL part" <- I don't quite understand this. Could you please elaborate? Also, there are no "url tags". Did you mean an anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display the URL in your object in apostrophes. Well, maybe you want this:

```
function openEventAdd(month,day,year)
{
var urlOb = "event_add.php?m=" + month + "&d=" + day + "&y=" + year;
urlOb="'"+urlOb+"'";

    $.modal({
        title: 'Add Event',
        url: urlOb,
        width: 300
    });
};
```